# Managing Large Data Sets in SQLite: Implementing Archive Methodology for Efficient Storage

Tags: c

I'm working on a project where I'm dealing with a high data rate of 10,000 records per second in a SQLite database using C. As the table grows, I'm looking to implement an archive methodology to ensure efficient storage and retrieval. Could anyone provide guidance on how to approach this issue? Specifically, I'm interested in strategies to archive records after reaching a certain number, ensuring data integrity, and optimizing retrieval performance .actually I have around 20 tables in that database, need to implement same approach for all tables. Any code snippets or best practices would be greatly appreciated.

I've experimented with two approaches so far:

1.Trigger Approach: I implemented a trigger that fires after reaching a certain number of records. However, this method is proving to be inefficient as it significantly slows down the insertion process, and I'm unable to achieve the desired rate of 10,000 records per second.

2. Timer Approach: Another attempt involved using a timer to check the database every minute, copying and then deleting records if a certain threshold is reached. Unfortunately, this method also falls short of my performance goal.

I'm seeking advice on optimizing these approaches or exploring alternative methods to efficiently manage the insertion of 10,000 records per second. Any insights or code snippets to improve performance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum.  Questions appropriate for this site will afford relatively short, complete answers that can be objectively evaluated for correctness.

Comment: I note, however, that SQLite is designed to be small, and simple to install and use.  It is *not* designed for either high capacity or high performance.  What you describe would be challenging for any DB, but I'm inclined to think that SQLite in particular is just not up to it.

Comment: Why delete old records at all?

Comment: Insert into a new table for each group of rows.  Batch inserts, say, 1000 records at a time.  Truncate the old tables as needed.